# Software Center disappeared and system settings does not work

Tags: package-management, software-center

I was cleaning up software in Software Center that I no longer use and after uninstalling one package the Software Center disappeared - as well as the System Configuration tools, how can I restore the Software Center and configuration functionality?

---

Salve, stavo facendo un po' di pulizia tra i software che non mi interessano su software center e dopo avere disistallato uno Ubuntu Software Center è sparito e le Impostazioni di Sistema non funzionano. Aiuto vi prego! Sono nel panico. Come devo fare.

Comment: che versione di ubuntu hai? descrivere  cosa funziona adesso e cosa no.... impostazioni di sistema? quali... sia un po piu preciso per  favore cosi' posso aiutare

Comment: @suli8: do you mind translating the title as well?

Comment: @takkat  translation:  ubuntu software center disappeared  and system configuration(settings) do not work!  can't edit it, it's too long

Comment: Ciao suli8 funziona apparantemente tutto non c'è più nel dock laterale di sinistra l'icona software center e quando cerchi di aprire impostazioni di sistema(per capirci l'icona viola con la chiave inglese) apre Ubuntu funziona bene ma mancano queste due applicazioni. Come posso ripristinarle. Va bene anche se mi dai dei dati da mettere su terminale. Scusa il mio linguaggio poco informatico ma purtroppo non sono un grande espreto. Grazie filippo.

Comment: Il primo problema l'ho risolto attraverso questo con link: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:d_OIk50oi6YJ:www.linuxqualityhelp.it/supporto/viewtopic.php%3Ff%3D8%26t%3D9520+ubuntu+software+center+scomparso&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=ubuntu&source=www.google.com

Comment: ok, benissimo, e' lo stesso che pensavo e la risposta qui sotto dice la stessa cosa. fai un segno che e' quella la risposta giusta per gli altri dopo di te. mi riferisco alla risposta di JE2Tom. non ti preoccupare, siamo qui per aiutare... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To directly restore Software Center you need to re-install the `software-center` package. You can do so from the terminal with

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

If that doesn't restore your entire desktop there is a good chance that you will need to re-install the `ubuntu-desktop` meta-package. Try re-installing the `ubuntu-desktop` meta-package:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Synaptic package manager to reinstall the software center.